# ASP.NET MVC2 Post button has right values but doesn't send values to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a button who's code is generated like this:

```
 <% RouteValueDictionary dictionary2 = new RouteValueDictionary(); %>
        <% dictionary2.Add("EventID",0); %>
        <% dictionary2.Add("CustomerID",Model.customer.CustomerID.ToString()); %>
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("EventEdit", "Customers", dictionary2,FormMethod.Get,null ))
                   { %>
        <button type="submit">
            new event</button>
        <%} %>
```

The actual code generated:

```
<form action="/Customers/EventEdit?EventID=0&amp;CustomerID=1" method="get">

                <button type="submit">
                    new event</button>
                </form>
```

But the buttons calls this address:

> http://localhost:20588/Customers/EventEdit

and I get:

> The parameters dictionary contains a
>   null entry for parameter 'EventID' of
>   non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   EventEdit(Int32, Int32)' in
>   'TechRun.UI.Controllers.CustomersController'.
>   An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

Any Idea what am I doing wrong (there are other post buttons on that form, but they work ok).
Thanks.

Comment: Use the debugger to see what values are present.

Comment: I check the source code of the page and also using firebug - I get the right code: /Customers/EventEdit?EventID=0&amp;CustomerID=1. I've taken the values and pasted them on the address bar - and it worked ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492933.aspx):</strike>

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm(
    "EventEdit", 
    "Customers", 
    new { EventId = "0", CustomerID = Model.customer.CustomerID }, 
    FormMethod.Get))
{ %>
    <input type="submit" value="new event" />
<% } %>
```

Also make sure that there's no some javascript that could interfere with the form submission sending an AJAX request and forgetting to include the values. And finally make sure that `Model.customer.CustomerID` is not empty. Use FireBug to see exactly what is the request being sent to the server.

---

UPDATE:

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4):

> If the method is "get" and the action
>   is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes
>   the value of action, appends a `?' to
>   it, then appends the form data set,
>   encoded using the
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   content type.

This means that you should not use query string parameter in the form action with GET method. You need to use hidden fields inside the form to pass those values to the server.

Comment: tried, the code is ok, and it's the same using my way or your way. for some reason the parameters are "dropped" once clicking the button.

Comment: Changed it from From to ActionLink and it works OK. is it possible that have 2 forms on the same page caused this problem ? I know it should work in ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: @Dani, I am afraid the problem is somewhere else. There shouldn't be any problem having two forms in the same page as long as they are not nested because nesting HTML forms is not allowed.

Comment: I've checked, and they are not nested. Have no clue what may cause this, as the action in the HTML page is correct.

Comment: @Dani, I think the problem comes from the fact that you are using GET as form method. It looks like this doesn't work with query string parameters. They are not sent. As a workaround try placing hidden fields inside the form and set the `routeData` parameter of the `BeginMethod` to `null`. So try putting inside the form: `<%= Html.Hidden("EventID", "0") %><%= Html.Hidden("CustomerID", "Model.customer.CustomerID") %>`